# How do I authenticate using a token for POST request in Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to connect to a website by using a token-based authentication. I was using Net::HTTP to connect, but on the API page I could not find a way to authenticate myself with a token. I only saw something for user/password.

How do I do this?

EDIT:

Code Sample:

```
`require 'rubygems'
 require 'rest_client'
 require 'base64'

  require 'rubygems'
 require 'rest_client'
 require 'base64'

require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'logger'

url ="https://redcap.org/redcap/api/"
my_token= 'token value'
RestClient.post url, :token=>my_token`
```

This where I get an error.

The error I receive is:
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:
111:in `parse_url': undefined method`match' for # (NoMeth
odError)

Comment: We need to see a code sample, along with the URL you are trying to authenticate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Net::HTTP, but there exist several gems that make interfacing with an API easy. These include [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) and [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).

See more here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients

As for the token, different APIs deal with tokens in different ways. If you provide details (and preferably a code sample where you demonstrate what you've tried) you'll get more specific help.

Comment: Thanks for the response this helps a lot. So what I have so far in my code where it breaks is: Code: RestClient.post url,:token=> my_token, but then I get an error saying that there is an undefined method 'match'. Do you think this is because I am improperly adding my token?